# What is the meaning of "a column of four place numbers"?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

In the sentence,

> Such software is referred to as threaded, or multi-threaded.
>   The software adding, say, **a column of four place numbers** could drive the job into four threads:
>   Adding the 1s-place numbers, the 2s-place numbers, the 3s-place numbers, and the 4s-place numbers.
>   Each of those subtasks is directed to a different core.

It is from "How Computer Works" can be downloaded from http://epdf.pub/how-computers-work-9th-edition.html

What is the meaning of "**a column of four place numbers**"? And/or what is the meaning of "**adding a column of four place numbers**"?

I guess four place numbers are like "1234". Right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the source? What’s the surrounding paragraph or context? You can [edit] your post to include more details.

Comment: It is from "How Computer Works" can be downloaded from https://epdf.pub/how-computers-work-9th-edition.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. The explanation is that each decimal place can be added in a separate thread, and then the results summed. E.G.

```
 2345
+5678
-----
```

Thread A adds 5+8, gets 13
Thread B adds 4[0]+7[0], gets 110
Thread C adds 3[00] + 6[00], gets 900
Thread D adds 2[000] + 5[000], gets 7,000
Finally, a new thread would add those results. Not necessarily the *fastest* way to do the operation, but it illustrates multithreading.

Comment: Thank you for your easy-to-grasp example!